# How to model multilingual objects in Python using webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, wtforms

I build a multilingual web app using Python and webapp2.

I have an object called Tag, which has translations to multiple languages. For this reason, I have created the following models:

```
class Language(ndb.Model):
    code = ndb.StringProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)


class MultilingualText(ndb.Model):
    language = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Language)
    text = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=False)


class Tag(ndb.Model):
    translations = ndb.StructuredProperty(MultilingualText, repeated=True, indexed=False)
```

I would like to ask if this is the correct way to do such task, and how this structure can be used along with WTForms for validation, etc.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: WtForms and Jinja2 support localisation (I18n) and Babel. I suggest you study those tools, and look if they fit your project goals. Normally this is the way to go.

Comment: Some questions -  Are you likely to want all translations for a given tag each time you get a tag ?  How big could a piece of text be ?  If you are do not need all translations all of the time, you might be better off keeping each translation a child of the tag, with the key being the langauge, and then only fetching a given translation depending on the users language.  Just some thoughts ;-)

Comment: @DimitrisMarkis please see the answer and make any comments !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best implementation can change depending on your goal and my answer here may not fulfill your needs.

For `Language` class, I would rather not use datastore for this purpose. I would use `babel.Locale` for determining display names.

As Tim said in the comment, I prefer using language code as the entity key. Here is an example `Tag` implementation, assuming every `Tag` needs a urlsafe slug.

```
def get_urlsafe_slug_from_tag(tag_text):
    # ...
    # ...

class Slug(ndb.Model):
    # use urlsafe slug as the key_name
    # You can optionally use the property bellow.
    available_translations = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)

class Tag(ndb.Model):
    # use language code as the key_name
    text = ndb.TextProperty()
```

When a tag is newly created, I will create two entities; a `Slug` entity with a unique urlsafe string (slug) for that tag as the key, as well as a `Tag` entity with the language code as the key and this `Slug` entity as its parent.

In this example, there is a property named available_translations, which will allow you to negotiate with the users language choices, and even execute a query which will return Slugs with a translation for a specified language (e.g. list Slugs with Japanese translation).

For WTForm validation, can you tell me how you want to validate the post data? I think you will be able to get better answer if you share your detailed needs.

Comment: What would the possibilities be for WTForm validation?